Optional to undefined in type
I want to map all optional fields of an object to required fields with undefined as option.
From
{ isOptional?: string, required: number }

To
{ isOptional: string| undefined, required: number}

I can't find the reason why this won't work. Playground
type IsOptional<T extends {}, K extends keyof T> =
  { [P in keyof T]?: T[P] } extends Pick<T, K> ? true : false;

type OptionalInfo<T extends {}> = { [P in keyof T]-?: IsOptional<T, P> };

type OptionalToUndefined<T extends {}> = {
  [P in keyof Required<T>]: OptionalInfo<T>[P] extends true
    ? T[P] | undefined
    : T[P];
};

type test1 = OptionalInfo<{ isOptional?: string; required: number }>;
// {isOptional: true, required: false}

type test2 = OptionalToUndefined<{ isOptional?: string, required: number }>;
// {isOptional: string, required: number}


That's a lot of work you're doing. I'd probably write OptionalToUndefined as shown here unless you have some use case you're not showing. If that meets your needs I'll write it up as an answer; if not, what am I missing?

thanks for your help. It solves my problem. Could you explain what (keyof T & {}) does?

I will explain in the answer.

The easiest way I know of to convert optional properties to required ones without stripping undefined is to write a mapped type which is intentionally non-homomorphic (see What does "homomorphic mapped type" mean?).  Homomorphic mapped types preserve the optional modifiers on properties (which you don't want). You could use the -? mapping modifier but that strips undefined as well.  On the other hand, a non-homomorphic mapped type will just copy the property read types without the modifiers.  Since the read type of an optional property includes undefined, you'll get that in the required output property.
So then you want a mapped type very much like {[K in keyof T]: T[K]} except that it's not homomorphic.  The in keyof bit is the hallmark of homomorphic mapped types. The way to prevent it is to stop TypeScript from seeing that you're mapping over the keys of some specific type it knows. Like this:
type OptionalToUndefined<T> = { [K in ({} & keyof T)]: T[K] }

By intersecting keyof T with the empty object type {}, we're not changing the set of keys, because all property keys are already compatible with the empty object type (see How to undestand relations between types any, unknown, {} and between them and other types?). So {} & keyof T is equivalent to keyof T. But TypeScript doesn't "see" that equivalence inside the generic type definition. So it decides that ({} & keyof T) is just some set of keys it's iterating over and doesn't see its direct relationship to T. Thus the property modifiers from T are not copied.
Let's test it:
type Test2 = OptionalToUndefined<{ isOptional?: string; required: number }>;
/* type Test2 = {
    isOptional: string | undefined;
    required: number;
} */

Looks good.
Playground link to code
